# How to get onError error message for React-Native Image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I get the error message for the onError event loading an Image in React-Native?

I've tried:

```
onError={({ nativeEvent: {error} }) => console.log(error) }
```

and also

```
onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
```

The first prints "undefined" the second prints nothing.

Comment: Android or iOS?  Http or https?

Comment: Android. Local image. @jmargolisvt

Answer (score 0):

You can print the error message by doing:

```
<Image
    source={yourImageSource}
    onError={error => {
       console.log(error.nativeEvent);
    }} 
/>
```

This will print something as:

```
{error: "Failed to load https://bucket.s3-us-e…", target: 7809}
```